# Efficient way to store messages, ID them, and get back to them easily

Tags: typescript, algorithm

I have a bot that after receiving a message from X user, sends a message somewhere and receives a response that he sends back to the X user. The X user can then send another message depending on the response he recieved that the bot will reply the first response and sends back the second response to X user.
I need to have a way to store all thoses responses to an ID and be able to get back to them.

Thanks in advance.

I tried using a map with a key as the ID and the response as an array to store the others, but I have issue keeping track of that ID.
var messageWaiting = new Map<any,[any,any,""]>()

Here is an example :

Poui to the Bot : "Hi 123"

Bot to a service : "123"

Service to bot : "XXX" (This is the first response)

Bot to Poui : "XXX"

Bot to Poui :"If you want to interact more, write "{id}' at the begining of your message"

Poui to bot : "{id} U1"

Bot to Service *response to the first reply* :"U1"

Service to Bot : "YYY'(this is the second response)

Bot to Poui : "YYY"

Comment: _"The X user can then send another message depending on the response he recieved that the bot will reply the first response and sends back the second response to X user."_ Can you clarify this with an example?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur I added an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost certainly your real problem is how to handle the async code.  There are three strategies for async code:

1. Callbacks
2. Promises
3. `async` / `await`

I will assume you know what they are.  If not, you can find them explained in lots of places.  For example [this blog post](https://blog.bitsrc.io/keep-your-promises-in-typescript-using-async-await-7bdc57041308).  (Note, it may take a certain amount of trial and error for the explanations to make sense.)

I'll finish my explanation using JavaScript because I know it better.  But translating between JavaScript and typescript is fairly easy.

Now the trick is that you want to have code for dealing with Poui that looks something like this:

```
async function processUserInput (..., input, ...) {
    let message = messageFrom(input);
    // will find with an id if one exists, else generates a new ID.
    let serviceCommunicator = serviceCommunicatorFrom(input);
    let response = await serviceCommunicator.request(message);
    sendToUser(response);
    ....
}
```

OK, we've just shoved the problem elsewhere, how does this help?

The `serviceCommunicator` is an object with the following fields.

1. `id` the id of the object.
2. `fromUser`, array of messages from the user.
3. `toUser`, array of promises with the replies TO the user.  They are added immediately, but will be resolved as they are resolved.
4. Whatever else you find useful.

And now we can keep all service communicators in a map by `id` allowing us to get back to them easily.  Literally if you're passed an `id`, just look it up and return it.  If not, construct a new object with  new id, add it to the map, and return that instead.

And how does `serviceCommunicator.request(message)` work?  We start off something like this:

```
function ServiceCommunicator(id):
  const that = this;
  this.id = id;
  this.toUser = [];
  this.fromUser = [];
  this.request = async function (message) {
    that.fromUser.push(message);
    let messagePosition = that.fromUser.length;
    // NO await HERE!!
    let response = that.requestFromService(message);
    that.toUser.push(response);
    let responseMessage = await response;
    return [messagePosition, responseMessage];
  };
  this.requestFromService = async function (message) {
    // do async stuff here
    return responseMessage;
  };
}
```

And now each request gets the right response AND the `serviceCommunicator` knows all things the user has said, which have been responded to, and if it was responded to, what the response was.

Note that the response returned internally also includes the position in the array for this message.  If you actually want to look at previous messages/responses in your logic, knowing where you are in that stream may be very helpful.

(Note, responses may come out of order with this strategy.  That is fixable, but this explanation is already long enough.)